# How to decompose a permutation as desired? $(1,2,3,4,5,6,...,12)$ how to decompose this into permutation of order 3 and 4?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I tried to do $$(1,2,3,4,5,6..,12)=(1,12)(1,11)...(1,2)$$

and

$$(1,2,3,4,5,6..,12)=(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)...(11,12)$$

and then in each method I tried to decompose them as

$$(1,2,3,4,5,6..,12)=(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)...(11,12)=\underbrace{(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)}_{(1,2,3,4)}.(4,5)(5,6)(6,7)(7,8)...(11,12)$$

but how to arrange them? What is the general method to do that? I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different way to begin - as a hint (you will need to do a little work to make this work). Let your permutation be $x$, then $x=x^{13}$. So try working with powers of $x$ to get the decomposition you want ...

Comment: Yeah I did it. the only possibility is $f^9\circ f^4=f$ 
and because $f^9$ is order 4 and $f^4$ is order 3, the desired elements are found.

Comment: @Jale'dejaleuffnejale Well done!